# Which manuals should I study before flying to France, Portugal and Switzerland?

Tags: regulations, caa-uk-regulations, eu, france, rules-of-the-air

I am from Brazil. My crew and I will fly to France, Portugal and Switzerland. I am accustomed to flying to the USA, but it will be my first time to Europe, and I am studying the differences. Which documents and manuals do you recommend that I study and read? (Note: I want names not resource location)

Comment: Doesn't your company have materials to prep you for entry into these countries? Maybe I'm not getting it clearly, but are you saying that you and your "crew" are the airline crew, or some other kind of crew?

Comment: We are corporate pilots.

Comment: We do have materials, and they will pay a course too, but we'd like to read more about procedures, contingencies and etc.

Comment: I am looking for the "International Route Manual" in which there are details about some aiports there.

Comment: There is a lot to learn, especially about the crossing but also about the differences in the way that they do things.  I would highly recommend taking an International Procedures course. These are offered by the major training centers, as well as various online / home study courses.

Comment: All these country are member of EASA (equivalent to FAA in europe) and apply it's rules, i'm not very concerned about Air Ops but I think you can find more information here : https://easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/air-operations

Answer (score 1):

1. For common procedures and or VFR rules you want to check the respective countries' AIP:

   - Switzerland   http://www.skyguide.ch/en/services/aim-services/
   - the other countries you mentioned can be found from this link collection http://www.eddh.de/equipment/ais.html
2. you may want to check the website of Eurocontrol here you can find IFR standard arrivals and departures

No warranty! Please prepare your flight carefully.